Finding multiple value positions in a large vector
I have two very large ordered vectors of integers v and w. What is the most efficient way of finding the positions of the entries of w with values in v? I am hoping for something way more efficient than doing a binary search for every number in v. (Planning to implement it in C++.)
EDIT: Per request, an example: if v={3, 10, 20} and w={2,3,5,11,15,20} then I need to find positions i=1 and i=5 because w[1]=3 and w[5]=20. Now imagine that v has size 10^10 and w size 10^11.
EDIT2: Vectors have no duplicates. The numbers in vectors have 20 digits. So they are too large to put a hash table (index table) of values of v in memory.

Hint: Think about the merge operation in merge sort. You're looking for conditions when v[i] == w[j]. The easy way of course is std::set_intersection, but it would probably try to sort the already-sorted lists first.

std::set_intersection will not help, because I am looking for positions of certain values in vector w. However, I see indeed a solution which involves labeling all entries of v by "v" and all entries of w by "w" and then merging and sorting them all. That may be what you suggest.

Yes, v and w need to be sorted.

Please show a good input+output example and a simple reference implementation for clarity/testing.

This is trivially done in linear time.
Track the current index in both w and v. For each index in w, iterate through v until you find an item that's bigger or equal. If it's equal, then emit the index.
//emits the indecies of items in A that are also in B
template<typename AIter, typename BIter, typename DIter>
DIter set_union_indecies(AIter a_first, AIter a_last, BIter b_first, BIter b_last, DIter dest) {
    unsigned index = 0;
    while (a_first != a_last) {
        // find the next item in B thats at least as big as the current item in A
        while(b_first != b_last && *b_first < *a_first)
            ++b_first;
        if (b_first == b_last) return dest;
        // if they're the same, then emit the index
        if (!(*a_first < *b_first))
            *dest++ = index;
        // check next value in A
        ++index;
        ++a_first;
    }
    return dest;
}

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c28a23cc26e50d79
As long as they're reasonably similar in size, then this is O(v+m) with a very tiny constant. If they're wildly different in size, then you may want something that's more of a divide-and-conquer.  I think that would still be O(w*logN) (or vice-versa) though, so not orders of magnitude faster than a binary search per-element.

I'd rename set_union_indecies to set_intersection_indices and A and B to w and v (it's confusing to use different names).
